# How to write Jquery to submit the clicked form in the for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to submit the selected form output in Jquery. Instead I'm getting all the other form data also

```
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    {% for obj in product %}
                        <form id="add-form" method="GET" action="{% url 'cart' %}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ obj.seller }}</td>
                            <td><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;{{ obj.price }}</td>
                             <td>

                                <label for="quantity">Qty: </label>

                                 <input min="1" class="input-sm" type="number"  name="qty" value="1" />

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input  class="inputid" name="item" type="hidden" value="{{ obj.id }}"/>
                                <!--<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-primary" href="#">Add to Cart&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> -->
                                <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-primary"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </form>
                  {% endfor %}
                </table>
```

Jquery I'm trying to use to submit

```
        $(".submit-btn").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = $(".add-form").serialize();
            console.log(formData);

        })
```

Output in Console Log(Getting all the forms data submitted(qty and item are output of each form)

output : qty=1&item=2&qty=1&item=12&qty=1&item=3&qty=1&item=9

Comment: `add-form` within the form tag is an `id` not a `class`. Why is your `formData = $(".add-form").serialize();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs must be unique in a document, but your code looks like it will add a duplicate ID for each product. As @TonyM states in their comment, you should change that to a class rather than an ID.

But if you do that, your submit handler will serialize every `.add-form` in the document--probably not what you want. Instead, use the nearest `form` element ancestor:

```
$(".submit-btn").on("click", function(event) {
  var form, formData;
  event.preventDefault();
  form = $(this).closest("form");
  if (form) {
    formData = form.serialize();
    console.log(formData);
  }
});
```

It's also possible to keep the default button behavior and suppress the form submission with a submit handler on the form itself. That way you're always operating on the correct form scope and don't have to muck about with navigating up the ancestor chain:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var formData = $(this).serialize();
  console.log(formData);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Palpatim and Tony... add-form is actually a class not id...Palpatim.. I have used default button behaviour and it's giving the result. Thank you very much